# OLA ImportError: No module named ClientWrapper

Tags: python, ubuntu-16.04

I'm trying to use [OLA](https://github.com/OpenLightingProject/ola) on Ubuntu 16.04 with Python 2.7.12. After installing the package (ola-python) through apt-get, I can see it at

> /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ola.

However, when I run basic [examples](https://github.com/OpenLightingProject/ola/blob/master/python/examples/ola_devices.py) from the OLA I get an error:

> ImportError: No module named ClientWrapper

This appears for the line:

```
from ola.ClientWrapper import ClientWrapper
```

Both

> /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages

and

> /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ola

are in sys.path, so I'm confused about what's going on here.

How do I get this package do work on Ubuntu?

Comment: What is the result of `$/usr/bin/env python --version`?

Comment: version is: Python 2.7.12

Comment: What about `$/usr/bin/env python -c 'from ola.ClientWrapper import ClientWrapper'`?

Comment: No output from that command

Comment: Very weird, because that means that the module actually exist and that can be imported from the python version '`$/usr/bin/env python`. Try to import change directory in the shell to where the example is and after entering into the Python interactive mode, do `from ola.ClientWrapper import ClientWrapper` and then import the example file. The idea is to force the example module to be imported on a Python interpreter that already imported the problematic module.